# Do UILocalNotifications persist after uninstall/update?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

It seems that UILocalNotifications scheduled by our app are fired even if the app gets overwritten with the production app (OK, expected behaviour) but also if the app gets uninstalled and then installed again. Did anyone experience this? (I am double checking and keeping the question as reference, did not find any duplicates).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of... they persists after unistall of the app probably for some hours, but they are not fired. 
You can test by yourself, launch your app in debug schedule some notifications, delete the app, install the app again and ask `UIApplication` for its scheduled notifications. You should see them again.
I think that Apple created this pattern to avoid accidental unistallations.
If you want to delete them create a BOOL flag in `NSUserDefault` to understand if it is the app first launch. If it is delete all the notifications.
`NSUSerDefault` doesn't persist after unistall (Keychain yes), so when you delete the app you can be sure that at the next install notifications will be wiped out.

Comment: So it seems they get fired too (I tried uninstalling on iOS 8.3, delay of two minutes since the first scheduling).

Comment: In my experience I've seen the behavior of unscheduling after uninstall, but not the firing. And the fact that you have evidence about that scares me :)

Answer (score 0):

If, on iOS 8.3, a UILocalNotification with a two minutes delay gets scheduled, then the app gets uninstalled and installed again, the notification gets fired.